Changing ESP mount point from /boot to /efi
I have recently installed Arch and now my system is triple-booted with Windows, Debian and Arch with GRUB bootloader, but recently while updating intel-ucode in Arch, I found out that the ESP is quite small 260Mb out which 251Mb is used.
This made me think of resizing it but after searching a little I found that the typical mount point of ESP for Arch can be changed to /efi, reducing size requirement.
I tried searching for the steps to do that and found this page. I followed through the steps but now I am unable to boot into Arch.
Here is what I did in the order:

changed /boot to /efi in /etc/fstab
mkdir /efi
umount /boot
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /efi/ (my ESP is at /dev/nvme0n1p1)
pacman -S linux intel-ucode
mkinitcpio -P

Thanks.

Which bootloader are you using for Arch?

@grawity_u1686 I am using grub.

The problem isn't that the ESP mountpoint moved, but that the OS kernel moved with respect to the bootloader (which is still in the ESP).
Your bootloader needs to know where the vmlinuz kernel image is (as well as the adjacent initrd or initramfs), and since it runs before Linux, it cannot rely on the Linux paths for that. So even though the file still gets installed at /boot/vmlinuz-linux from the Arch point of view, that now corresponds to a different partition physically (and potentially a different filesystem type), so the grub.cfg needs to be updated accordingly.
In other words, you need to repeat the GRUB installation: chroot from Debian (or from an Arch USB), then re-run grub-install (so that it would bring in the GRUB modules necessary to access your / filesystem – especially if it's on LVM/LUKS/Btrfs), finally re-do grub-mkconfig (so that it would generate a grub.cfg that knows where the kernel is).
Make sure to specify --efi-directory=/efi when installing GRUB as it won't auto-detect that.

Although I had some severe grub issues after that, I managed to fix them and now ESP is 96MB used and 164MB free. Thanks
